# Can not install Angular Cli

Tags: angular

What I am trying to do is very simple and that is installing angular CLI, however I get the following issue

```
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.4.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.4.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.4.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1
```

I ran the following command `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` but I get the error shown in the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiM26.png)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with node-gyp folder.

Delete your **`$HOME/.node-gyp`** directory and try again.

Refer **[Github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809)** for more details.

Comment: How can I get to that directory in mac? I cant find it in my /Users/{username}

Comment: so I should delete my node in my /usr/local/bin directory?